# How to recombine 4096 matrice in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

```
W = [0:255];
A = reshape(W,[16,16])'
[a b] = size(A);
c=4;
d=4;
l=0;
for i=1:c:a-3
  for j=1:d:b-3
    C=A((i:i+3),(j:j+3));
    eval(['out_' num2str(l) '=C'])
    l=l+1;
  end
end

combineagain = [out_0 out_1 out_2 out_3; out_4 out_5 out_6 out_7; out_8 out_9 out_10 out_11; out_12 out_13 out_14 out_15]
```

This is a code with the help of which I split and then recombine a matrix. In the last assignment (`combineagain`) I manually substitute all the outputs in order to get the result back. I need want to substitute all of these outputs with the help of a code.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please read the formatting help that is available from within the question editor window!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating variable namees programatically using `eval` is a bad idea. You have found out one of the reasons for this.

One approach you could follow here would be to use a cell array to capture all the components within the loop:

```
W = [0:255];
A = reshape(W,[16,16])';
[a b] = size(A);
c=4;
d=4;
l=0;
C = {};
for j=1:d:b-3
  for i=1:c:a-3
    l=l+1;
    C{l}=A((i:i+3),(j:j+3));
  end
end
C = reshape(C,[c,d]);
combineagain = cell2mat(C)
```

I switched the order of the two loops so that the `C` cell array would be in the right order. Generally it is best to have the inner loop be over the first index.

If you don't want to change the loop order, you can also directly index into `C` to put the components into the right locations. For this I changed the indexing a bit:

```
W = [0:255];
A = reshape(W,[16,16])'
[a b] = size(A);
c=4;
d=4;
a = a/c;
b = b/d;
C = cell(a,b);
for i=1:a
  for j=1:b
    C{i,j}=A((i-1)*c+(1:c),(j-1)*d+(1:d));
  end
end
combineagain = cell2mat(C)
```